# Javascript: Milliseconds to a date

Tags: javascript, date, datediff

How would I go about to get the amount of milliseconds and a specific data. For Instance, i know how to create a date:

```
var d = new Date(2014,02,22,12,0,0,0);
```

and to get today's date:

```
(new Date()).getTime() + 10*24*60*60*1000;
```

But now how would I go about to get the total milliseconds until this date occurs?

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't you search Stack Overflow and the rest of the web?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var miliseconds = Math.abs(d - new Date());
var today = new Date() // empty constructor returns the "now" time.
```

Returns the number of miliseconds between the two dates. Using `Math.abs` ensures you always get a positive result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like the positive result!

Answer (score 2):

Well its a matter of subtracting.

```
var d = new Date(2014,02,22,12,0,0,0);
var today = new Date();

var ms = d-today;
document.write(ms);
```

Output:

```
28015951707
```

Comment: I went to check documentation to make sure I wasn't talking nonsense :x It's ok all credit due to alex23